# Server return Connection timed out but work locally

Tags: java, docker, https, connection

i have API service on my website to connect with other host like https://otherhost.com
when i test it on localhost it working and return correct response
but when i deployed to server it return error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)`

**Noted:**

1. in localhost and server use the same url > https://otherhost.com
2. i already use command ping, traceroute, telnet and it can find otherhost perfectly
3. i already add ip and hostname to my docker compose /etc/hosts file

Sample of my code

```
    String host = "otherhost.com";
    URL url = " https://otherhost.com/api/GetAccess.php?grant_type=authorization&scope=openid";

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] { new DefaultTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
    SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
    
    // start connection...
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    Set Header...
    con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
     String authStr = env.getProperty("authen");
     String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authStr.getBytes());

    con.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", base64Creds));
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        
    System.out.println("Status Code :: " + con.getResponseCode());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String responseLine = null;
    while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("response :: " + responseLine);
        response.append(responseLine.trim());
    }
        
    con.disconnect();
```